# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExecption:Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am a newbie Android Developer. I am trying to get a text input from user using and Edittext box and then convert that text into string and then into a char array of size 4. i have an array already stored that is of size 4 and it contains values. i want to compare both the arrays and perform a task based on the result.

I don't know why am i getting the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExecption

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newgame);

    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.guess);



    EditText guess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);


    boolean c=false;

    char[] guessword;
    char[] appword = {'T', 'R', 'U', 'E'};
    guessword = guess.getText().toString().toCharArray();


    for(int i=0;i<appword.length;i++)
    {
        if(guessword[i]==appword[i])
        {
            c=true;
        }
        else
        {
            c=false;
        }
    }

    final boolean correct=c;        


    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(correct){
                startActivity(new Intent(Newgame.this, Win.class));
            }
            else{
                startActivity(new Intent(Newgame.this, Loose.class));
            }

        }
    });



}
```

}

Comment: You want to compare the text after you click `submit`?

Comment: You are iterating through the appword array which has a length = 4. If a length of the entered word (guessword) is less that 4 you'll get an error because of `if(guessword[i]==appword[i])`

Comment: At a glance it looks like you could simply use `correct = guess.getText().toString().equals("TRUE");`

Comment: Using strings it the best solution.  BUT your code ends up only checking the last letters for matching (assuming you don't get an out of bounds exception first).  "T R U E" and "B L U E" will pass because they both end with "E".  You need to exit the for loop after the first false comparison.  You can use the break; statement for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `guessword` may have fewer than four characters, and your code does not check for that condition.

Change your code as follows to account for this condition:

```
for(int i=0;i<appword.length;i++)
{
    if((i < guessword.length) && (guessword[i]==appword[i]))
    {
        c=true;
    }
    else
    {
        c=false;
        break; // <<<=== Add this to end the loop
    }
}
```

Also note that your code as written does not "lock in" the `false` when characters are not equal to each other: for example, `{'A','B','Z'}` and `{'X', 'Y', 'Z'}` will compare equal under your old algorithm. Add `break` to exit the loop as soon as you see a `false`.

Comment: This Code Works ! The app is not crashing anymore also am not getting that Error. But The problem now is that I entered TRUE in the text box but still it Started the Activity - LOOSE whereas it should have started WIN

Comment: (Upvote for your great explanation) Since Ishan Khanna is checking the value of `guess` in onCreate(), `guessword` will always be empty (or whatever the initial value of `guess` is). This check should happen in `submit`'s onClick and can be simplified to `if(guess.getText().toString().equals("TRUE")) startActivity(new Intent(Newgame.this, Win.class)); else startActivity(new Intent(Newgame.this, Lose.class));`

Comment: But i want to do the checking letter by letter and yes i need it to be done when the user clicks on the button

Comment: @Sam Your Method Didn't Work For Me ! After I Entered TRUE It still took me to Loose.class :(

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are going with the index from 0 to the value of the `appword`.

Take for example the case in which the user types in: "NO". Because you are iterating over `appword` which has the length greater than your actual text, when you do a `guessword[i]` it will crash throwing your `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I am not sure why you are using `char[]`. As I can see, for your example, `String` could solve the problems.

```
String appword = "TRUE";
String guessword = guess.getText().toString();
```

Then, the method that shows if the 2 are equal is :

```
if (appword.equals(guessword))
```

If you also want to match the case, use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead.

Answer (score 0):

guessword is null when you walk over the first time (which happens in the onCreate). One thing you could do is change

```
 if(guessword[i]==appword[i])
```

to

```
 if(guessword != null && guessword.length =< i && guessword[i]==appword[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compare the entered text to "TRUE", you can simply do:

```
String guessword = guess.getText().toString();
if ("TRUE".equals(guessword)) {
   ...
}
```